# What are the subquery equivalents of SQL aggregate functions MAX/MIN/AVG/COUNT

Tags: mysql, sql, function, subquery, aggregate

Can someone show me how to represent the following SQL statements without the use of aggregate functions?

`SELECT COUNT(column) FROM table;`

`SELECT AVG(column) FROM table;`

`SELECT MAX(column) FROM table;`

`SELECT MIN(column) FROM table;`

Comment: I have no idea what you mean.  Why do you want to avoid aggregate functions when they are the right solution?  What constructs are you allowing?  Can you give an example?

Comment: I agree with @GordonLinoff: you want to aggregate your data without using aggregate functions?  Why?

Comment: Without use of sum or count.  I'm w/ @Gordan. unless you use variables...

Answer (score 2):

`MIN()` and `MAX()` can be done with simple subqueries:

```
select (select column from table order by column is not null desc, column asc limit 1) as "MIN",
       (select column from table order by column is not null desc, column desc limit 1) as "MAX"
```

`COUNT()` and `AVG()` require the use of variables, if you don't allow any aggregations:

```
select rn as "COUNT", sumcol / rnaas "AVG"
from (select t.*
      from (select t.*,
                   (@rn := @rn + 1) as rn,
                   (@rna := @rna + if(column is not null, 1, 0)) as rna,
                   (@sum := @sum + coalesce(column, 0)) as sumcol
            from table t cross join
                 (select @rn := 0, @rna := 0, @sum := 0) const
            order by column
           ) t
      order by rn desc
      limit 1
     ) t
```

This latter formulation only works in MySQL.

EDIT:

The empty table is a challenge.  Let's do this with a left outer join:

```
select cast(coalesce(rn, 0) as int) as "COUNT",
       (case when rna > 0 then sumcol / rna end) as "AVG"
from (select 1 as n
     ) n left outer join
     (select t.*
      from (select t.*,
                   (@rn := @rn + 1) as rn,
                   (@rna := @rna + if(column is not null, 1, 0)) as rna,
                   (@sum := @sum + coalesce(column, 0)) as sumcol
            from table t cross join
                 (select @rn := 0, @rna := 0, @sum := 0) const
            order by column
           ) t
      order by rn desc
      limit 1
     ) t
     on n.n = 1;
```

Notes.  This will return `0` for the count if the table is empty.  That is correct.  If the table is empty, it will return `NULL` for the average, and that is also correct.

If the table is not empty, but the values are all NULL, then it will also return `NULL`.  The types for the count are always integers, so that should be ok.  The type of the average is more problematic, but the variables will return some sort of generic numeric type, which seems compatible in spirit.

Comment: +1 I think the `@sum := column` expr should really be `@sum:=@sum+IFNULL(column,0)`. (It should be accumulating the values, but we want to ignore NULL values. Replacing NULL with zero is the easiest, although we do have the odd behavior that a SUM of all NULL columns would be 0, rather than NULL. (The expressions required to handle the SUM of "all NULL" values would be a little more involved.) The COUNT and SUM are really still doing aggregation, they are just doing it less efficiently using some MySQL specific behavior, with a lot more syntax. But right on with the MIN and MAX.

Comment: Also, there's also a corner case of table t being empty. We could do a `... FROM () const LEFT JOIN (... FROM table ...)` to ensure we get at least one row back. And, we really need to "count" the number of non-NULL values of column to calculate the AVG, i.e. we'd need a `@cn` counter like `@rn`, but increment it only for non-null values. And we'd also probably want to handle a potential "divide by zero" (cn=0) in calculating AVG as well. The `COUNT` and `AVG` returned are a close approximation of `AVG()` and `COUNT()`, but they need more work to get them to be equivalent.

Comment: @spencer7593 . . . I think I fixed the myriad errors.  The empty table is a good point.  A bit of a challenge, but I think I got it.

Comment: I'd +1 your answer again if I could, looks better. I've got a statement working, if you need an example, feel free to adopt anything you like from it to improve your answer. NOTE: the expression `if(column is not null, 1, 0)` can be shortened a bit, to just `(column is not null)`. There's probably things in my query that can be shortened or eliminated, but the way it's written makes sense to me.

Comment: Now, how about adding `GROUP BY` functionality  without using a `GROUP BY`? (I kid, I kid.) But, it is possible, I've done it before. The "trick" was to have the inline view spit out the values from the previous row (from user variables, together with the values from the current row, and then filter on just the "new" rows, which included the values from the "last" row of the previous set. To get that to work, I had to append a dummy row with special values at the end, using a "UNION ALL". (I don't want to count the number of derived tables that were involved.)

Comment: @spencer7593 . . . That particular operation is done quite often in databases that support window/analytic functions.  In some ways, I think it would be better to teach those first and then only teach `group by` later.

Comment: MIN ignores NULL values, but your example with the order by column asc would return the first NULL value.

Comment: @SenseException . . . Good catch.  I fixed t hat.

Answer (score 1):

min/max can be replaced with something like this:

```
select t1.pk_column, 
       t1.some_column
from the_table t1
where t1.some_column < ALL (select t2.some_column
                            from the_table t2
                            where t2.pk_column <> t2.pk_column);
```

For getting the `max` you need to replace `<` with `>`. `pk_column` is the primary key column of the table and is needed to avoid comparing each row to itself (it doesn't *have* to be a PK it only needs to be unique)

I don't think there is an alternative for `count()` or `avg()` (at least I can't think of one)

<sup>I used `the_column` and `the_table` because `column` and `table` are reserved words</sup>

Answer (score 0):

SET @t1=0, @t2=0, @t3=0,@T4=0;

**COUNT:**

```
Select @t1:=@t1+1 as CNT from table
order by @t1:=@t1+1 DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Similar methods could be put together for Avg and max/min using limits...

Still thinking about Min/Max...

Answer (score 0):

Not to supersede the excellent answer from Gordon Linoff, but there's a little more work involved to accurately emulate the `AVG()`, `COUNT()`, and `SUM()` functions.  (The answer for the MIN and MAX functions in Gordon's answer are spot on.)

There's a corner case when the table is empty. In order to emulate the SQL aggregate functions, we need our query to return a single row. But at the same time, we need a test of whether or not the table contains at least one row.

Here's a query that is a more precise emulation:

```
-- create an empty table
CREATE TABLE `foo` (col INT);
-- TRUNCATE TABLE `foo`;

SELECT IF(s.ne IS NULL,0,s.rn)   AS `COUNT(*)`
     , IF(s.cc>0,s.tc,NULL)      AS `SUM(col)`
     , IF(s.cc>0,s.tc/s.cc,NULL) AS `AVG(col)`
  FROM ( SELECT v.rn
              , v.cc
              , v.tc
              , e.ne
           FROM ( SELECT @rn  := @rn + 1                    AS rn
                       , @cc  := @cc + (t.col IS NOT NULL)  AS cc
                       , @tc  := @tc + IFNULL(t.col,0)      AS tc
                    FROM (SELECT @rn := 0, @cc := 0, @tc := 0) c
                    LEFT
                    JOIN `foo` t
                      ON 1=1
                 ) v
            LEFT
            JOIN (SELECT 1 AS ne FROM `foo` z LIMIT 1) e
              ON 1=1
           ORDER BY v.rn DESC
           LIMIT 1
       ) s
```

---

**NOTES:**

The purpose of the inline view aliased as `e` is to give us a way to determine whether or not the table contains any rows. If the table contains at least one row, we'll get a value of 1 returned as column `ne` (not empty). If the table is empty, that query won't return a row, and `e.ne` will be NULL, which is something we can test in the outer query.

In order to return a row, so we can return a value, like a `0` for a COUNT, we need to insure that we return at least one row from the inline view `v`. Since we are guaranteed exactly one row from the inline view aliased as `c` (which initializes our user defined variables), we'll use that as the "driving" table for a `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` operation.

But, if the table is empty, our  our row counter (`@rn`) coming out of `v` is going to have a value of 1. But we'll deal with that, we have the `e.ne` we can check to know if the count should really be returned as 0.

In order to calculate the average, we can't divide by the row counter, we have to divide by the number of rows where col was not null. We use the `@cc` user defined variable to keep track of the count of those rows.

Similarly, for the SUM (and the average) we need to accumulate only the non-NULL values. (If we were to add a NULL, it would turn the whole total to NULL, basically wiping out are accumulation. So, we're going to do a conditional test to check if t.col IS NULL, to avoid accidentally wiping out the accumulation. And our accumulator is going to be a 0 if there aren't any rows that are not null. But that's not a problem, because we'll make sure we check our `@cc` to see if there were any rows that were included. We're going to need to check it anyway, to avoid a "divide by zero" issue.

To test, run against the empty table `foo`. It will return a count of 0, and NULL for SUM and AVG, equivalent to the result we get from:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(col), AVG(col) FROM foo;
```

We can also test the query against a table containing only NULL values for `col`:

```
INSERT INTO `foo` (col) VALUES (NULL);
```

As well as some non-NULL values:

```
INSERT INTO `foo` (col) VALUES (2),(3),(5),(7),(11),(13),(17),(19);
```

And compare the results of the two queries.

---

This essentially the same as the answer from Gordon Linoff, with just a little more precision to work around the corner cases of NULL values and the empty table.